# AWS Lambda cloudwatch logs throw "Failed to load events" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function with the following permissions[image]

whenever the lambda function is triggered, I see a log file being added to the logstream in cloudwatch. 
[image]

When I try to open any of the logs, it throws ***Failed to load events
Unexpected error loading events*** error. Please help with fixing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. The issue was: my 'Authorization' header has been modified. In my case — I added it using chrome extension for the testing purposes

Comment: Ha ha ha. Me too.  Would never have thought of that.

Comment: What does this mean?  How do you "fix" the header?  And what is "chrome extension"?

Comment: If you don't know what that means then it shouldn't be your issue, it's a way to change the data your browser sends for development purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I saw the same error using Firefox but got the expected results using Chrome. So use Chrome to view CloudWatch.

Comment: I also got this error when using Brave. I disabled the Shields (in the location bar) and then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. I suspect it had something to do with AWS's recent DNS issues. I had to go into my router's settings and change from dynamic DNS to static DNS. I used servers 1.0.0.1 and 1.1.1.1. Hope this helps someone!